# Hanging a ethernet and television cable between 2 buildings

Tags: wiring, ethernet, television

I want to connect to the internet and television (via cable) 2 buildings. In the 1st building is the main internet router and the main television cable. I want to bring the internet and tv cable to the 2nd building. The distance is about 7-10m and I want to hang the cable using steel wire rope.
I have a few questions:

1. What type of steel wire rope should I use ?
2. Can you show me a detailed schematic of the installation of the steel wire rope ?
3. How can I install on the steel wire rope the internet and tv cables ?

Comment: Have you looked at a wireless access point instead?

Comment: how well is that going to work for CATV?

Comment: Running new cable TV wire in 2022 is a waste.  I tore out all the coax from my house years ago.  Use direct subscriptions to TV services and use fiber or wireless between buildings.

Comment: We run heavy light strings from our house to trees in large backyard 15ft ish off the ground. Used clothes line with the wheels. Install easy, zip tie, turn wheel, zip tie, turn wheel. Can easilly  hold coax and eithernet cable, and install is easy

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Answer (score 4):

This is SELV so the rules are very relaxed compared to power wires.

> What type of steel wire rope should I use ?

One that's strong enough and sufficiently durable, if you're near the coast I would recommend stainless steel for all parts of the support rig, if you're outside the salt-spray zone galvanised steel will list decades, and the extra cost of stainless is probably not justified.

> Can you show me a detailed schematic of the installation of the steel wire rope ?

attach the anchors to structurally sound parts of the buildings, use cable thimbles on the ends of the wire.
raise the wire and tighten the turnbuckle.
do a search on electrical catenary.

> How can I install on the steel wire rope the internet and tv cables ?

There are many options.
eg uv-resistant cable ties (black nylon, or stainless steel) or you can attach rigid plastic conduit to the caternary wire and put the signal cables inside that. (reccomended if you have wildlife that likes to eat cables)

All cables should be rated for use in wet locations (even if you use conduit)

Comment: ...and grounding. Lightning does **love** exterior cable links. Makes me very fond of all dielectric fiber.